# How to create a DragEvent in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I need to simulate `DragEvent` for testing purpose. However I am not able to access `DragEvent.obtain()` method.

Please suggest a way to `simulate DragEvent` such that I can define actions for DragEvent in onDrag() method of DragListener

For Touch MotionEvent, we could do so by MotionEvent.obtain() and passing relevant parameters, however this method is not accessible in case of DragEvent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DragEvent.obtain()** is an internal API function which is not exposed yet as seen by **@hide** annotation.

As a wayaround, you can create a DragEvent from parcelable object
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/DragEvent.java#488

```
DragEvent.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeInt(action);
parcel.writeFloat(x);
parcel.writeFloat(y);
parcel.writeInt(0); // Result
parcel.writeInt(0); // No Clipdata
parcel.writeInt(0); // No Clip Description
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
```

If you want to add Clipdata, see it's createFromParcel() method.

Comment: Can you please describe more. I too need to implement DragEvent programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am providing you some very nice tutorials which will guide to implement the `DragEvent` in android. You can refer it and implement it for your testing purpose.

**EDITED LINKS:**
1) [Link1](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/touch-and-drag-in-android/)
2) [Link2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)
3) [Developer Site for Drag Event](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Grishu. But all these links explain only about using DragDrop API'S. If you look at OnDrag method of DragListener, it accepts a parameter DragEvent. When using touch android handles creating this DragEvent and defining it's action. But as a requirement, I need to create it myself.  Updated my question for more clarity.

Comment: Hey i have changed my answer according your requirement please check out. Thanks for clearing your question.

Comment: Thanks Grishu, but this doesn't answers the question. I need to create a DragEvent to pass in listView.dispatchDragEvent(DragEvent dragEvent). How to generate this dragEvent parameter.

Comment: This is not about how to create DragEvent at all! ((